# Large delay between FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN flow element and FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN

Tags: flow, debugging, performance

We have a flow, and have noticed it has greatly increased the time it takes for a bulk (200 record) transaction to complete.

We've narrowed down the delay to a 78 second delay between **FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN** and **FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN**, with Workflow Debug Logs set on finer (the most detailed level available for Workflow). As we're unable to get any more granular on the logs, it's challenging for us to debug further. I'm opening a case with support, but wanted to reach out to here as well, in case others have noticed similar behavior.

For what it's worth, the flow is kicked off via Process Builder, and the first element is an 'Assignment' element, in order to [bulkify this flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53481/how-to-bulkify-headless-flow) as much as possible.

Once we get into the flow, I am able to see logs for each **FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN** and **FLOW_ELEMENT_END**, and there seems to be nothing out of the ordinary, with each element only taking a few milliseconds.

**Debug log:**

```
### LOGGING LEVELS

Category       Level    Events
Database       NONE 
Workflow       FINER    WF_RULE_INVOCATION; WF_APPROVAL; WF_FIELD_UPDATE; WF_SPOOL_ACTION_BEGIN; WF_ACTION; WF_FORMULA; WF_RULE_EVAL_BEGIN; WF_RULE_EVAL_END; WF_RULE_EVAL_VALUE; WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN; WF_CRITERIA_END; WF_RULE_ENTRY_ORDER; WF_RULE_NOT_EVALUATED; WF_RULE_FILTER; WF_ESCALATION_RULE; WF_ESCALATION_ACTION; WF_TIME_TRIGGERS_BEGIN; WF_TIME_TRIGGER; WF_ACTIONS_END; WF_ENQUEUE_ACTIONS; WF_APPROVAL_SUBMIT; WF_APPROVAL_SUBMITTER; WF_APPROVAL_REMOVE; WF_NEXT_APPROVER; WF_EVAL_ENTRY_CRITERIA; WF_PROCESS_FOUND; WF_SOFT_REJECT; WF_HARD_REJECT; WF_PROCESS_NODE; WF_ASSIGN; WF_REASSIGN_RECORD; WF_RESPONSE_NOTIFY; WF_OUTBOUND_MSG; WF_ACTION_TASK; WF_EMAIL_ALERT; WF_EMAIL_SENT; SLA_PROCESS_CASE; SLA_NULL_START_DATE; SLA_EVAL_MILESTONE; SLA_END; WF_KNOWLEDGE_ACTION; WF_SEND_ACTION; WF_CHATTER_POST; WF_QUICK_CREATE; WF_FLOW_ACTION_BEGIN; WF_FLOW_ACTION_DETAIL; WF_FLOW_ACTION_END; WF_FLOW_ACTION_ERROR; WF_FLOW_ACTION_ERROR_DETAIL; WF_APEX_ACTION; FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN; FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_END; FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_ERROR; FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_BEGIN; FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_END; FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_ERROR; FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN; FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END; FLOW_INTERVIEW_PAUSED; FLOW_INTERVIEW_RESUMED; FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN; FLOW_ELEMENT_END; FLOW_ELEMENT_FAULT; FLOW_ELEMENT_DEFERRED; FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR; FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN; FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_END; FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_DETAIL; FLOW_ASSIGNMENT_DETAIL; FLOW_SUBFLOW_DETAIL; FLOW_RULE_DETAIL; FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT; FLOW_LOOP_DETAIL; FLOW_ACTIONCALL_DETAIL; FLOW_WAIT_WAITING_DETAIL; FLOW_WAIT_RESUMING_DETAIL; FLOW_WAIT_EVENT_WAITING_DETAIL; FLOW_WAIT_EVENT_RESUMING_DETAIL;
Validation     NONE     
Callouts       NONE     
Apex Code      NONE
Apex Profiling NONE     
Visualforce    NONE
System         NONE 

### 78 seconds between FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN and next debug element. yikes.

11:37:09.970 (36970849164)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN|FlowActionCall|myRule_1_A1
11:38:28.448 (115448118602)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|xxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing this issue if multiple flow versions are defined in the org.

There is a bug logged in Salesforce for the same

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000182MBQAY

Comment: hmm -- interesting, thanks for the link. We never got to the root cause, but we definitely did have multiple versions at the time of writing this post.

Comment: @Mikey looks like Salesforce has fixed this issue. Are you still facing this issue ?